# Use header application/x-download

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend framework 1. Physically, the file does not exist, it is created based on database.

Okay so use header?

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
    $optin = new Application_Model_Optin();
    //$data = $optin->getCodesFromDownload($id);
    $data = array(
        array('code' => 12345),
        array('code' => 12346),
        array('code' => 12347),
        array('code' => 12348),
        array('code' => 12349)
    );

    header("Content-type: application/x-download");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=code_" . $id . ".csv");

    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        echo $item['code']."\r\n";
    }
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is perfectly acceptable.

This [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628260/downloading-a-file-with-a-different-name-to-the-stored-name) post demonstrates that the header is simply used for naming the file.